# ForbiddenAttributesError with CanCan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancancan

In my BrandsController I have the following two param methods:

```
def create_brand_params
  params.require(:brand).permit(:name, content_attributes: %i[app_name app_launcher_name])
end

def update_brand_params
  params.require(:brand).permit(content_attributes: %i[id app_name app_launcher_name])
end
```

And then the controller has permissions like so:

```
load_resource :client
load_and_authorize_resource :brand, through: :client, shallow: true
```

And finally the abilities:

```
can :manage, Client, id: Client.owned_clients(user.id).map(&:id)
can :manage, Brand, client: { id: Client.owned_clients(user.id).map(&:id) }
```

So in short, a user can only manage Clients and Brands where they have ownership of the Client. This works fine on the Client and also for most of the Brand methods except creating a Brand. When I try and create a new Brand I get the following error: `ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError`

But I am able to edit a Brand fine... Why am I getting this error for create but not update?

To clarify, a user can only create a Brand for a Client they own so I can't disable CanCan for the create method. To fix the issue I've had to add this hack in for now:

`load_and_authorize_resource :brand, through: :client, except: :create`

Which protects the new method but allows the create which isn't what I want...

Comment: check what params you are getting while creating brand

Comment: I remember having similar problem before. And the reason I found out was that the #edit and #update actions are "member" actions, while for example #new, #create, and #index are "collection" actions. To put simply, these member actions work properly when you pass the `id:` as you showed above in your **abilities.rb**, primarily because these records ALREADY have an ID. However, on #create action, the record does not yet have an `id`. I am not sure the better way to handle, but what I did was I pass the `params` into the `Ability #initialize` from the ApplicationController.